# Validate collections on the client side with DataAnnotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I've been successful in adding custom client-side validations in ASP MVC, in part thanks to [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/613330/Building-Client-JavaScript-Custom-Validation-in-AS). The unobtrusive system works well when you only need to validate one object at a time.

Now I need to perform validations on a collection type to check properties of the entire collection. I feel this should be possible but can find no documentation at all of how to do this. For starters, which HTML element is responsible for keeping track of the data attributes?

**Example code**

```
public class Model {
    [ListNotEmpty]
    public IEnumerable<Submodel> Submodels { get; set; }
}

public class Submodel {
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}

public class ListNotEmptyAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable {
    public override bool IsValid(object value) {
        return ((IEnumerable<Model>) value).Any(m => m.Selected);
    }

    // FormatErrorMessage() elided

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(
                ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context) {
        yield return new ModelClientValidationRule {
            ErrorMessage = "You must select at least one!",
            ValidationType = "listnotempty",
        };
    }
}
```

With this code, validations happen at the server side no problem but no client-side validation attributes are created at all. Neither are there any error messages.

I could forgo the DataAnnotations framework and just roll my own Jquery validations but DataAnnotations works so well for me in other cases.

Could someone please advise me? Is this kind of validation at all possible with ASP MVC?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to validate? The only thing that really makes sense with a collection is ensuring that at least one item exists in it, but even then, that one item may itself be completely invalid because of requirements on its properties. Validating a collection property, at least with something as simplistic as a data annotation, just doesn't make sense, which is pretty much why nothing exists for that out of the box.

Comment: Yes, checking that a list is not empty is a very good example. I can provide one example that I think makes perfect sense: The user is presented with checkboxes. He must check at least one of them. Then when we have ensured that, it would be up to the elements to validate other properties on themselves.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I changed my question to a more concrete example.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing.  I found this URL.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340205/mvc-dataannotation-validation-rule-for-a-collection   but I can't get the popupmessages to show up on my Silverlight page.  Yeah, SL, boo.